# Reliable way to measure RAM usage of desktop application

Tags: c#, memory, process

I'm working on an automated testing system (written in C#) for an application at work and I have great difficulty to measure the peak ram usage that it needs e.g. while loading certain files (memory usage is typically much higher during file loading).

First I tried to use `Process.PeakWorkingSet64` and it worked quite well on the machines in use at that time until the testing system got deployed to more machines and some VMs.
On some of these machines `PeakWorkingSet64` was way higher than on others (e.g. 180MB vs 420MB).

I tried different other values of `Process` and also tried to use `PerformanceCounter` but I don't know any other metric that gives me a peak value (I really want the peak not the current state).

I don't really get my head around why the `PeakWorkingSet64` value is so much higher on some systems.  I always run the exact same software with the exact same workloads on these machines. So if I have a software that allocates 1GB of data in RAM I also expect that every system it runs on reports a max memory usage of around 1GB.

Is there something important I'm missing here?
Any hints what I could do to measure memory usage reliably from within the testing system?